# How do you merge two bones into one?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a generated mesh and set of bones from a makehuman model but it created two bones in the shin.

How do I merge the two selected bones into one bone but keep the skeleton intact, i.e. the knee and foot where it should be.

[image: Model with rig of two selected bones to be merged]

Comment: Saw this title on Hot Network Questions, and I wondered, *when did we get a MadScience.Stackexchange site?*

Comment: @MasonWheeler LOL. Welcome to blender.SE ( 3D software.) PS there is a [MadScience.SE](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @David: Oh, so now we're putting bones in a blender?  Out of context, that sounds really creepy! ;)

Comment: @MasonWheeler We also deal with severed monkey heads and such.

Comment: and python smoothies!

Comment: @MasonWheeler - we even give those severed monkey heads names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The universal way to delete something in Blender and merge surrounding elements to a single object is to use *Dissolve* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>). It works for meshes, nodes, bones and grease pencil points.

[image: Dissolve]

Comment: I like this better than Alt-M

Comment: Is there an advantage of doing it this way as opposed to the ALT M way?

Comment: @ChrisStone With this way, your model's weights are much less likely to get screwed up.

Answer (score 11):

With the two bones selected like in the picture in your question, simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.
That will merge the two bones and take care of the bone relations.

[image: animated gif]

---

**Or** You could achieve the same thing in more steps by deleting the two bones, and "filling" a bone between the two ends that are left. Then going and editing the *Bone Parent* and checking *Connected* for the top bone.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did try ALT M but I was in pose mode and I was wondering why nothing was happening, Doh!  By the way, how did you make those neat little animations?

Comment: @ChrisStone sorry if I never got back to to (or if I did you can just ignore this) Read [What is the process for creating gifs for questions and answers?](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/963/2217) I wrote up my whole process there.